# Multilanguage Site: Display Modal Based on HTTP Accept-Language

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, http, multilingual

I am in the midst of building a bootstrap website that is predominately intended for Mandarin-speaking audiences. There is though, some percent of the user base which would like to view the website in English. I will have two version of the website, one at the main domain: xyz.net and the other as a sub-domain at en.xyz.net. By default, users will view the xyz.net site, so I am trying to set up a Modal to be displayed once upon startup for users whose HTTP 'Accept-Language' does **not** include: zh, zh-Hans, or zh-Hant (Chinese language codes). This Modal would be a very brief pop-up that states something along the lines of:
"Looking for the English site? Redirect here: ..." and would then link to the other sub-domain: en.xyz.net

What is the best approach for displaying this Modal dynamically?

I have intentionally decided to not use IP Address Location as a means of deciding which users to display this too because there will be users in both China and the US who will be accessing the site in Mandarin.

Answer (score 0):

To display the Modal dynamically, you can check the following steps:

1. Check the `Accept-Language` header in web server, save "whether it supports Chinese" information into HTML response using template technology.
2. In HTML, assign the above information to global variable (`window`).
3. After page is loaded, check the above information from global variable (`window`). If Chinese is not supported, popup the Modal.

Here is an example in Node.js (using Express framework and Nunjucks template):

**Step 1.** Check `Accept-Language` header and save information to response.

```
function isChineseAccepted(acceptLanguages) {
  // check whether zh, zh-CN or zh-Hans etc is accepted, return true or false accordingly.
}

router.get('/sample-page', function(req, res) {
  var acceptLanguages = req.get('Accept-Language');
  var isChinese = isChineseAccepted(acceptLanguages);
  res.render('views/sample-page', {
    isChinese: isChinese
  });
});
```

**Step 2.** In HTML, assign the `isChinese` information to the `window` global variable

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.isChinese = '{{isChinese}}';
</script>
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

**Step 3.** After page is loaded, check `isChinese` from `window`. Popup Modal if it's "false".

```
$(function() {
  if (window.isChinese === 'false') {
    // Popup Modal using Bootstrap.
  }
});
```